# Elixir: Delete a value from a Nested Map

Tags: elixir

Elixir provides a bunch of helper functions in [`Kernel`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html) that let you get and update values from a nested [`Map`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html) or another struct that implements [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html):

- [`get_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2)
- [`put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#put_in/3)
- [`update_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/3)

**But I couldn't find anything that could help me delete a value.** I know I could just update the value to `nil` (or just not be lazy by fetching the nested map, deleting the value and putting the whole map in), but I was hoping for a simple one liner that would actually delete the value that maybe I missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After googling a bit I decided to post this as a feature request in the official elixir mailing list, only to find out that it [has already been requested](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elixir-lang-core/iWeo3YFw1xw/g1wVjsRMBgAJ), **and an alternative does exist**. It's [`Kernel.pop_in/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#pop_in/2), which returns the deleted value and updated map in a tuple:

```ex
pop_in(%{user: %{name: "John", age: 27}, [:user, :age])
# => {27, %{user: %{name: "John"}}
```

---

José's reasoning for not having a separate `delete_in/2` method:

> The reason why we choose `pop_in/2` is because it provides more features than `delete_in` on its own and we want to avoid overloading Kernel with too many functions. If your concern is chaining, you can always perform `a |> elem(1)` after popping.

Comment: FWIW, let me post it here as a shameless plug. [`Iteraptor`](https://hexdocs.pm/iteraptor/Iteraptor.html#content) package provides helper functions to deeply iterate nested structures.